# Distance to rect edge from point based on direction

Tags: mathematics, python

I have a rect that is at position (0,0) at the top left and is 2200x2200 in size.

I am trying to specify the the distance to get to the edge of the rect in specific direction (degrees) from a point within the rect.

So say I am at point 50,50, and want to move 270 degrees until I hit the coordinate of the edge of the rect. What would be the best way to go about this?

Right now I have another function I use to get distance based on direction

```
distance = 2200
direction = 315
toEdge = distance*math.cos(math.radians(direction)), distance*math.sin(math.radians(direction))
```

This will just get a point 2200 units away from direction. I think this is half the step there, but can't get the math right on on how I translate this into getting the distance to the rect edge depending on coordinate.

If anyone could help me out I would be appreciative. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intersection of a Line and a Rectangle](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111100/intersection-of-a-line-and-a-rectangle)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you're asking ,after you get your toEdge point , you need [Intersection of a Line and a Rectangle](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111100/intersection-of-a-line-and-a-rectangle/111104#111104) to get intersection point. Then calculte distance from start point to intersection point.