# I need to find intersection point of a vector in an axis aligned rectangle

Tags: cocos2d-x, intersection, c++

I need some help, I have one vector in a rectangle like following

[image: the vector in the square]

(Ops, first A2 point on the top should be A1, assume it is A1)

Let's say the vector is like above It doesn't have intersection point actually, Basically, I need to find the point A1 and A2

I'm using cocos2d-x but framework specific solutions are not mandatory
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intersection of a Line and a Rectangle](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111100/intersection-of-a-line-and-a-rectangle)

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate... In this case it's more like a projection. @FoxitcL Do you really mean a square or can it be a rectangle, like in the image? Is it always axis-aligned or can it be rotated?

Comment: Yes, Its always axis aligned and its rectangle. Updating the question sorry for the missing info

Comment: How is your vector stored? Is it two points? A point and an offset? A point, an angle and a length?

Comment: I store it with a point, angle and a length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to project the vector onto the correct sides of the rectangle. Using the tangens function we're already halfway done. The rest is basic trigonometry.

**Input data**
Depending on how you store the rectangle, we have to transform the input data first. This method expects a rectangle that is defined solely by it's size (width `w` and height `h`). It's top left corner lies on the origin [0,0].
The Y-axis of the coordinate system expands downwards <sup>(1)</sup>.

We expect the point `p` to always be inside the rectangle. The angle is defined in radians.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct Vec2
{
    float x, y;
    Vec2() : x(0), y(0) {}
    Vec2(float X, float Y) : x(X), y(Y) {}
};

typedef std::pair<Vec2, Vec2> Result;

// a  d
// b  c
struct Rect
{
    Vec2 a, b, c, d;
};

void project(const Rect& rect, Vec2 p, float angle, Result& output)
{
    float tanA = tan(angle);

    // Avoid division by zero
    if(tanA == 0)
    {
        output.first.x  = rect.d.x;
        output.first.y  = p.y;
        output.second.x = rect.a.x;
        output.second.y = p.y;
    }
    else
    {
        // Transform input (make p relative to rectangle)
        p.x -= rect.a.x;
        p.y -= rect.a.y;

        float w = rect.d.x - rect.a.x;
        float h = rect.b.y - rect.a.y;
        calcProjection(w, h, p, tanA, output);

        // Transform result back to original coordinates
        output.first.x  += rect.a.x;
        output.first.y  += rect.a.y;
        output.second.x += rect.a.x;
        output.second.y += rect.a.y;
    }
}


int main()
{
    Rect rect {
        Vec2(400, 600), // Top left
        Vec2(400, 700), // Bottom left
        Vec2(600, 700), // Bottom right
        Vec2(600, 600)  // Top right
    };

    Vec2 p(550, 650);
    float angle = -M_PI_4;

    Result result;
    project(rect, p, angle, result);

    std::cout << "A1: x=" << result.first.x  << " y=" << result.first.y  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A2: x=" << result.second.x << " y=" << result.second.y << std::endl;
}
```

**Projection Algorithm**
The basic idea is like this:

1. Use `tan()` and offsets to project `p` onto sides *CD* and *AB*. Result: `yCD` `yAB`
2. Check for boundaries.
3. If outside, project `yCD` and `yAB` onto *DA* or *BC* using trigonometry.

[image: Projection on CD and DA]

```
void calcProjection(float w, float h, const Vec2& p, float tanA, Result& output)
{
    float yCD = p.y - (tanA * (w - p.x));
    float yAB = p.y + (tanA * p.x);

    if(tanA < 0)
        tanA = -tanA;

    // First projection onto CD
    if(yCD < 0)
    {
        output.first.x = w + (yCD / tanA);
    }
    else if(yCD > h)
    {
        float opposite = yCD - h;
        output.first.x = w - (opposite / tanA);
        output.first.y = h;
    }
    else
    {
        output.first.x = w;
        output.first.y = yCD;
    }

    // Second projection onto AB
    if(yAB < 0)
    {
        output.second.x = -yAB / tanA;
    }
    else if(yAB > h)
    {
        float opposite  = yAB - h;
        output.second.x = opposite / tanA;
        output.second.y = h;
    }
    else
    {
        output.second.y = yAB;
    }
}
```

Note: The first result `A1` will always be on the right side of the rectangle. `A2` always on the left. If you want `A1` to be on the front and `A2` in the back of the vector, you can swap them when the following condition is true: `angle >= PI/2 || angle <= -PI/2`

I should also note that I haven't fully tested any of this.

<sup>(1)</sup> When using a coordinate system where the Y-axis expands upwards, simply negate the input angle: `angle = -angle`

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply, will try it soon and let you know

Comment: It works perfectly, I just completed porting it to cocos2dx. Thanks again :)

Comment: I couldn't up-vote your answer btw, if you could approve my question I might fill the required reputation to vote

Comment: Glad it worked. I already upvoted your Q. No problem, don't bother.